# Assign value to column based on lookup table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following matrix:

```
destinations = ["DC","NY","SF","AL"]

workinDays = [[3, 5, 7, 7], 
                [5, 5, 7, 7],
                [7, 7, 7, 7],
                [7, 7, 7, 7]]

working_days_df = pd.DataFrame(data=workinDays, columns=destinations,
                 index=destinations).astype(str) + " working days"
```

Based on the above matrix (When you run the above code you'll get a matrix in a dataset form) I want to assign value to another dataset `other_df` which has upto 100 rows:

```
dest1   dest2
DC      DC
NY      AL
...
```

So I want to add a new column which reads the correct value from the matrix above. For example in row 2 `dest1` is NY ad `dest2` is AL. So based on the matrix it's value should be 7. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can perform a lookup:

```
df_other['new'] = working_days_df.lookup(df_other['dest1'], df_other['dest2'])
```

Here, `working_days_df` is your matrix DataFrame, while `df_other` is the one you'd like to lookup values for.

Comment: This just transforms the current dataset, but doesnt map to this other dataset that he is mentioning. Can edit that with a merge, as in my solution.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Just noticed and fixed, thanks.

Comment: DataFrame.lookup is deprecated since version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following -

```
df1 = df.unstack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['dest1', 'dest2', 'workingdays']

#the second dataframe that you mention is the other_df
pd.merge(other_df,df1,how='left',on = ['dest1', 'dest2'])
```

```
dest1   dest2   workingdays
0   DC  DC  3 working days
1   DC  NY  5 working days
2   DC  SF  7 working days
3   DC  AL  7 working days
4   NY  DC  5 working days
5   NY  NY  5 working days
6   NY  SF  7 working days
7   NY  AL  7 working days
8   SF  DC  7 working days
9   SF  NY  7 working days
10  SF  SF  7 working days
11  SF  AL  7 working days
12  AL  DC  7 working days
13  AL  NY  7 working days
14  AL  SF  7 working days
15  AL  AL  7 working days
```